# Difference of contents in Shurman's Calculus and Analysis in Euclidean Space and Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, soft-question

My question is simple: How much do *Calculus and Analysis in Euclidean Space* by Shurman and *Calculus on Manifolds* by Spivak differ in the topics they discuss? I am not necessarily meaning which book has more difficult exercises, but in a sense is either of the books a proper subset of the other? I would like to better my analysis skills to a more rigorous level, and I am looking for a material that would do the trick in a multivariate setting similar to Baby Rudin in single variable analysis.

Comment: Baby Rudin itself covers much of the material that is covered in Calculus on Manifolds, by the way. Another book to be aware of is Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres. I also recommend Hubbard and Hubbard, which covers vector calculus and calculus on manifolds and which tries hard to be very readable (unlike Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, which is wonderfully short but for me has always been difficult to learn from). I haven't looked at Shuman but it looks good; I'm going to check it out.

Comment: @littleO, are you sure about "Shuman"? What' name of book?

Comment: It should be  "Jerry Shurman", @littleO. Not "Shuman".

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for catching that.

Comment: @littleO I am currently reviewing from Baby Rudin and I am not yet at the later chapters (beyond chapter 7) so I can't speak from experience, but I have heard that the latter portion of the book is a bit of lackluster compared to the first seven chapters. If you were to teach/re-learn rigorously measure theory, integrability and multivariable analysis, would Baby Rudin be in your list of references, or would you turn to some other book?

Comment: I would spend some time on baby Rudin but I'd focus more on other books like Tao's Analysis 2, Hubbard and Hubbard, Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres, Sheldon Axler's new book [Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis](https://measure.axler.net/), Multivariable Mathematics by Shifrin... I like to look at several books simultaneously and focus on whichever one is connecting with me. Terence Tao's Analysis 2 is a very good place to start, in my opinion.

Comment: I've just begun looking at Shurman's book and so far I like it quite a lot. Looks like a very good choice for you @EpsilonAway.

Comment: @littleO Great! It is always good to have an opinion from someone more experienced. At least I have found that besides some classic texts, it can be hard to find an opinion on a newer book which might actually improve some well-known classic, as the general guideline given is that "if the text XXX is equivalent to YYY, then it is good". The issue is that a beginner can really only determine the equivalence by reading both texts :D.